# Syntax issue with a nested if statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, nested-if

Modelsim is telling me there is a syntax issue with my nested if statement and I can't determine what the problem is. Any help would be great!

```
when ZERO =>
        if X_REG = '0' then 
            zero_sig <= '1';
            if zero_count = '15' then
               nextState <= ONE;
            else
               nextState <= ZERO;
            end if;
        else
            nextState <= ZERO;
            zero_reset <= '1';
        end if;
```

Comment: At least the `zero_count='15'` looks wrong.  Also, make the indentation match the `if` structure.

Comment: And a little more direct - `'15'` isn't a character literal, nor are the declarations visible for any of these signals and or variables. Was the 5 extraneous, or is there an equality testing zero_count and an integer literal?  Your example isn't complete without declarations. What ever needs to be fixed appears to revolve around that equality condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `zero_count` is a numeric (for example integer) type:

```
when ZERO =>
    if (X_REG = '0') then 
        zero_sig <= '1';
        if (zero_count = 15) then
           nextState <= ONE;
        else
           nextState <= ZERO
        end if;
    else
        nextState <= ZERO;
        zero_reset <= '1';
    end if;
```

Yeah, I know that parentheses are not required but IMHO they makes VHDL code more "readable".

Comment: David's comment on the original question explains the reason behind that one-line change.